# How can i push boxes in a tunnel in spritekit?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am working on a sprite-kit game. I can not walk in the tunnel. There are 5 boxes beside the tunnel and they are reside in a same line. The water in the tunnel is moving. Man can push the boxes in any direction. If the man wanted to escape the tunnel then he has to use this boxes. So he has to push this boxes and put those into the tunnel and also move the boxes with the speed of water in the tunnel. And also if one box pushed into the tunnel then Man can walk on the box and also he can push another box over the before placed box in the river and only the box portion on the tunnel will be collision free.

[image]

Hope this image explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your description does not give a clear picture of what you want to do... If you can attach some illustrations to help it would be much better..

Comment: I have added an image for better explanation. Hope this image explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, you meant to say river! I totally misunderstood when u said tunnel... anyways, please see my input in the answer

Answer (score -1):

You just need to give the collisionBitMask of the boxes' physicsBody to the player category and vice versa with the player's physicsBody. That way the player and the boxes will collide and the player's movement will affect that of the boxes.

Comment: This I know. But the river also the obstacle of the player. Player can not move through the river. If the man push the box on the river then box will move to river but how can I remove the portion of the river in the the box is reside will collision free for the player.

Comment: That you will have to check in your -update: method explicitly.